# how to get id of created document cloud functions Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In the function that listens to the creation of a new document. How do you get the id of that document

```
export const createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/messages/{messagesID}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const newValue = snap.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      const name = newValue.name;

      // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

I am guessing it is in the `context` argument. I am just not getting around to accessing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at the [documentation for Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events), which explains how to do what you want.  Pay special attention to the section on [using wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters).

The wildcards `userId` and `messagesID` in curly braces in your function definition are accessible in the given `context`.

```
const userId = context.params.userId;
const messagesID = context.params.messagesID;
```

You can also get the ID of the document from its snapshot using its [`id` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#id):

```
const id = snap.id;
```